# android admob refresh rate

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am properly showing ads on my app but they are not been refreshed. I tried to set refresh rate to 20s on admob app panel and also on xml as ads:refreshInterval. However, add is shown but no refreshed anymore. If I force programaticaly as follows, add is refreshed properly but not a suitable solution. Why adds are not refreshed? thank you

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();

adMob.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: how can you tell that ad is not refreshed? you see the same ad for a long tine or you don't see in logs when ad is refreshed ?

Comment: both of them! same banner and also onReceivedAd not triggered